# How can I change the foreground color of a wxRadioButton?

Tags: c++, user-interface, wxwidgets

The method wxRadioButton::SetForegroundColour does not work (see http://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/10137).

Does anybody knows how to make it work? I don't understand the drawing process of wxWidgets controls, so if someone can provide pieces of code, it would be very appreciated.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

wxWidgets uses the native radio button control, so if you happen to be programming for Windows (using wxWidgets), the colors in most controls and dialog boxes are "inherited" from the colors defined in the Appearance tab of "Display Properties". If you must deviate from the system dictated themes, you may need to create your own radio button class.